# How to solve this deployment problem?, Only homepage seems to be deployed and other parts of the project are not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, websocket, deployment

There is only one static page getting deployed and not the entire project.
none of the buttons are working and there is no solution on the web for this as well

I tried deploying my project through firebase as well as netlify, but in both I'm facing same issue.

Meanwhile on LocalHost Everything seems to be working perfectly fine.

Here is the URL which is deployed:-
https://main--profound-monstera-d72b73.netlify.app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.